install specific version of pytorch
I am trying to install a specific version of torch (along with torchvision and torchaudio) for a project.
The instructions from the project mentioned the command:
pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

and for compatibility reason I installed (after some trial and error approach) on one machine using the command the following versions:
pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.htm

Everything seems fine in this machine. But when I tried to apply the same command on another machine there was a surprise.
pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.htm


Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.htm
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
torch==1.11.0+cu113 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0,
1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0, 2.5.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.11.0+cu113

So, there isn't any version specifically mentioning cuda version. Just the torch version. So, when I pick 1.11.0 it was installed successfully but with which cuda is not obvious.
From pip in cli it wasn't shown at all:
pip list | grep torch


torch              1.11.0
torchaudio         0.11.0
torchvision        0.12.0

but from inside python it can be seen (!):
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.11.0+cu102'

So, I guess cuda 10.2 was chosen by default for some reason. When inspecting the official torch docs the command provided is:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

and for 11.7 (the one I have in this machine):
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision) (2.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision) (11.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2024.8.30)

How can be satisfied when cuda 10.2 is selected?
Even for specific torch version 1.11.0 the output is the same:
pip3 install torch==1.11.0 torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.11.0 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch==1.11.0) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision) (2.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision) (11.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/orfanidis/miniconda3/envs/torch310/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2024.8.30)

For reference in the first machine the output was:
pip install torch==1.11.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.11.0+cu111 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.11.0+cpu, 1.11.0+cu102, 1.11.0+cu113, 1.11.0+cu115, 1.11.0+rocm4.3.1, 1.11.0+rocm4.5.2, 1.12.0, 1.12.0+cpu, 1.12.0+cu102, 1.12.0+cu113, 1.12.0+cu116, 1.12.0+rocm5.0, 1.12.0+rocm5.1.1, 1.12.1, 1.12.1+cpu, 1.12.1+cu102, 1.12.1+cu113, 1.12.1+cu116, 1.12.1+rocm5.0, 1.12.1+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.0+cpu, 1.13.0+cu116, 1.13.0+cu117, 1.13.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.0+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.0+rocm5.2, 1.13.1, 1.13.1+cpu, 1.13.1+cu116, 1.13.1+cu117, 1.13.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.1+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.1+rocm5.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.0+cpu, 2.0.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.0+cu117, 2.0.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.0+cu118, 2.0.0+rocm5.3, 2.0.0+rocm5.4.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.1+cpu, 2.0.1+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.1+cu117, 2.0.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.1+cu118, 2.0.1+rocm5.3, 2.0.1+rocm5.4.2, 2.1.0, 2.1.0+cpu, 2.1.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.1.0+cu118, 2.1.0+cu121, 2.1.0+cu121.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.1.0+rocm5.5, 2.1.0+rocm5.6, 2.1.1, 2.1.1+cpu, 2.1.1+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.1.1+cu118, 2.1.1+cu121, 2.1.1+cu121.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.1.1+rocm5.5, 2.1.1+rocm5.6, 2.1.2, 2.1.2+cpu, 2.1.2+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.1.2+cu118, 2.1.2+cu121, 2.1.2+cu121.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.1.2+rocm5.5, 2.1.2+rocm5.6, 2.2.0, 2.2.0+cpu, 2.2.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.2.0+cu118, 2.2.0+cu121, 2.2.0+rocm5.6, 2.2.0+rocm5.7, 2.2.1, 2.2.1+cpu, 2.2.1+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.2.1+cu118, 2.2.1+cu121, 2.2.1+rocm5.6, 2.2.1+rocm5.7, 2.2.2, 2.2.2+cpu, 2.2.2+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.2.2+cu118, 2.2.2+cu121, 2.2.2+rocm5.6, 2.2.2+rocm5.7, 2.3.0, 2.3.0+cpu, 2.3.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.3.0+cu118, 2.3.0+cu121, 2.3.0+rocm5.7, 2.3.0+rocm6.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.1+cpu, 2.3.1+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.3.1+cu118, 2.3.1+cu121, 2.3.1+rocm5.7, 2.3.1+rocm6.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0, 2.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.11.0+cu111

where the error messages is stating specific version which can be chosen.
So, my questions are:
a) Why on some machines torch can be provided with specific cuda version and on others no.
b) Is there any difference between the torch official command and the project's one? I know -f means find links
c) More important how can I install the specific version I need if half of the programs ignore the version I have now (as pip itself for example)?
The python version I am using in my venv is 3.10.9 in both machines but the drivers differ.
